# SQL number of distinct values for the value in another column

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table with user logins:

[image]

```
create table usr_logins
(
    id int primary key, 
    logint_date date,
    user_name text,
    os_ver int
);

insert into usr_logins
values (1, '2018-12-23', 'Jack', 10)
      ,(2, '2018-12-24', 'Sam', 11)
      ,(3, '2018-12-24', 'Jack', 10)
      ,(4, '2018-12-24', 'Ann', 10)
      ,(5, '2018-12-25', 'Sam', 10)
      ,(6, '2019-12-26', 'Sam', 10)
```

I need to get a list of user names with a number of different OS versions used by them.

Note that only Sam has logins from os_ver 10 and 11.

This is what I need:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to get all usernames and corresponding distinct os_version count displayed (as os_num), you can try the following:

```
select user_name, count(DISTINCT os_ver) as os_num from usr_logins group by user_name
```

Comment: Your query will return a number of logins for each user, while I need a number of different os_ver. For example I need a value of 1 for Jack because he uses the same os_ver both times while your query will give me 2. And I need 2 for Sam because he used os_ver 10 & 11 while your query will give 3.

Comment: You can use the DISTINCT keyword. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_name, count(distinct os_ver) osCount from usr_logins group by user_name having osCount > 1
```

Hope I understood you question correctly

Comment: your query will return a number of logins for each user, while I need a number of different os_ver. For example I need a value of 1 for Jack because he uses the same os_ver both times while your query will give me 2. And I need 2 for Sam because he used os_ver 10 & 11 while your query will give 3.

Comment: @Kosh, so I didn't understand your question correctly :) updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you are expecting *only* user Sam or not since you've highlighted in red, but if so you can do

```
select user_name, Count(distinct os_ver) os_num
from usr_logins
group by User_Name
having  Count(distinct os_ver)>1
```